# Filter after a group by in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to make a filter after a group by with spark.

I would like to have this after = group by :

| accountid | startdateacceleration | enddateacceleration |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0011t00000MYFRKAA5 | 2021-05-25 00:00:00.000000 | NULL |
| 0011t00000MYFRKAA5 | 2021-05-26 00:00:00.000000 | 2021-08-31 00:00:00.000000 |
| 0011t00000MYFRKAA5 | 2021-09-01 00:00:00.000000 | 2022-05-26 00:00:00.000000 |
| 0011t00000MYFRKAA5 | 2022-05-27 00:00:00.000000 | NULL |

And i want to have that

| accountid | startdateacceleration | enddateacceleration |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0011t00000MYFRKAA5 | 2021-05-25 00:00:00.000000 | NULL |
| 0011t00000MYFRKAA5 | 2021-09-01 00:00:00.000000 | 2022-05-26 00:00:00.000000 |

For every rows from my input i have to filter  rows  in the group which are between the first day of previous month from  startdateacceleration to startdateacceleration.

I.e : I will not take the second line of my input because it is in the intervall.

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll need to develop a method to parse "day" from your String type. You could use [java time parser](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html), or write a hacky method of your own to string splice.

Next, use one of the [dataset .filter methods](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.scala#L1578-L1604) to pass a boolean condition.